# Setting max/min values of Singleband grey layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers

I have a raster layer in QGIS and I would like to write Python code to change it's max and min values that would normally be under Layer Properties> Symbology> Band Rendering. The layer has a Singleband gray render. This is what I've written so far:

```
rLayer = iface.activeLayer()

rLayer.renderer().setClassificationMin(-426)
rLayer.renderer().setClassificationMax(8848)
```

Sadly it doesn't work for Singleband gray renders, only for Singleband pseudocolor.

Could anyone tell me what changes I should make to the code to make it work for the grayscale (Singleband gray)?

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/64539191/820534

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To configure the minimum and maximum values of a single band gray symbol you must configure the QgsContrastEnhancement

Apply and modify the values of the following code to see the effect

```
capa=iface.activeLayer()
renderer=capa.renderer()
provider=capa.dataProvider()
GrayRenderer = QgsSingleBandGrayRenderer(provider,1) #create a new renderer
   

#If you don't need to create a renderer but modify the existing one, start # 
#here and at the end apply the contrastEnhancement

myType = renderer.dataType(1)
myEnhancement = QgsContrastEnhancement(myType)
contrast_enhancement = QgsContrastEnhancement.StretchToMinimumMaximum
myEnhancement.setContrastEnhancementAlgorithm(contrast_enhancement,True)
myEnhancement.setMinimumValue(20.3)   #Set the minimum value you want
myEnhancement.setMaximumValue(50.5)   #Put the maximum value you want 
capa.setRenderer(GrayRenderer)
capa.renderer().setContrastEnhancement(myEnhancement)
capa.triggerRepaint()
```